Popover for each option in select2
I tried hovering over each option in select2 and returning a corresponding popover. For example, when I hover over "Low effort" it returns this:
titlePop1
textPop1

and when I hover over "High effort" it returns this:
titlePop2
textPop2

But the effect is being applied to the entire container, i.e. to .select-results and not to each option.
Code:


<head>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js'></script>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3/animate.min.css'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wnumb@1.2.0/wNumb.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div id='pickerDivA1'>
      <h6>fadeIn</h6>
      <select id="testId">
        <option value="AL">Low effort</option>
        <option value="WY">High effort</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#testId').select2({
        dropdownParent: $("#pickerDivA1"),
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
      }).on('select2:open', function(e) {

        $('.select2-dropdown').addClass('animated flipInX');

        let titles = ['titlePop1', 'titlePop2'];
        let contents = ['textPop1', 'textPop2'];

        let $lis = $(this).data('select2').$dropdown.find('.select2-results__options');

        $lis.each(function(i) {
          if (!$(this).hasClass('select2')) {
            $(this).popover({
              html: true,
              sanitize: false,
              title: titles[i],
              content: contents[i],
              trigger: 'hover',
              placement: 'right',
              container: 'body'
            })
          };
        });

      }).on('select2:closing', function(e) {
        $('.select2-dropdown').removeClass('animated flipInX');
      });

    });

  </script>
</body>



I tried this too:
let $lis = $('#testId').data('select2').$dropdown.find('.select2-results__option--highlighted');

but not work.

You need to introduce a short delay for the lis to propagate. This means the event is firing too soon.


<head>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js'></script>
  <link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animate.css@3/animate.min.css'>
  <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/wnumb@1.2.0/wNumb.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <section>
    <div id='pickerDivA1'>
      <h6>fadeIn</h6>
      <select id="testId">
        <option value="AL">Low effort</option>
        <option value="WY">High effort</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </section>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#testId').select2({
        dropdownParent: $("#pickerDivA1"),
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownPosition: 'below'
      }).on('select2:open', function(e) {

        $('.select2-dropdown').addClass('animated flipInX');

        let titles = ['titlePop1', 'titlePop2'];
        let contents = ['textPop1', 'textPop2'];

        var $this = $(this)
        setTimeout(function() {
          let $lis = $this.data('select2').$results.find('li');
          $lis.each(function(i) {
            $(this).popover({
              html: true,
              sanitize: false,
              title: titles[i],
              content: contents[i],
              trigger: 'hover',
              placement: 'right',
              container: 'body'
            })
          });
        })

      }).on('select2:closing', function(e) {
        $('.select2-dropdown').removeClass('animated flipInX');
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>



